# How do I pass a string to a python program with ajax, and send a string back

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have an ajax request sending an object to a python program using json:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/python.cgi",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(myobject),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response){
            console.log("it's alive");
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('request failed');
        }
})
```

and python.cgi looks like

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import sys, json

input =sys.stdin

output = json.loads(input)

json.dumps(output, sys.stdout)
```

This code gives me

> TypeError: the json object must be 'str' not 'TextIOWrapper'

I don't understand why this is happening since I am passing my data as a string.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What if you try `json.load` (not `json.loads`).  The former operates on file-like objects, the latter operates on strings.

Comment: doing this gives me a 500 internal server error

Comment: Also, I assume you switched to `json.dump` instead of `json.dumps`?

Comment: I had not -silly me- but it gives me the same outcome

Comment: stdin is file like object, try `sys.stdin.read()`.

Comment: thank you! adding .read() did the trick, I also had to add a the correct header to my response: 'Content-Type: text/plain\n\n'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html, you should probably use the FieldStorage class instead of reading directly from standard input:

```
import cgi

print "Content-Type: application/json"
print

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

In `form` you would then have access to the data your expecting.

Comment: Should that be `Content-Type`?  And it looks like OP is trying to return a json response, so I'm not sure you've got the correct content type there :-)